# Alter text alignement in multiple tables - Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, alignment, tables

I Need to alter the alignment in multiple tables in indesign, but i don't won't to do it one by one (selecting all cells and then changing the alignment) since I have around 100 tables in my indesign document. Is there a way to apply this alignment edit to several tables at once?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using paragraph styles?

Comment: Is there a way to apply paragraph styles without having to enter en each table and apply ? I mean, select multiple tables, and apply the paragraph style to all of then ?

Comment: I believe you can just select the tables and then clcik on the desired paragraph style and it will apply to all selected. To speed this up, you can create a shortcut to the paragraph styles.

Comment: hum, this doesn't seen to work. This way it applies to the entire textbox, but not to the table which is inside the textbox (since you need a textbox to create the table, this doesn't seen to work by just selecting the textbox which the table is in). =( 

Thanks by the way. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try a character style instead of a paragraph style.

Comment: @JVS a character style won't work because you can't apply alignment to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built-in way to select multiple tables. Like @JVS said, this can be done with paragraph styles. If all of the tables in the document need to be modified, you can do this using table styles instead of applying manually.

1. Create a new paragraph style with the alignment you want
2. Change the table style options to use the new paragraph style for the appropriate cells

If you haven't been using table styles before, then all of your tables are probably assigned the [Basic Table] style. If you have tables that you don't want to modify, you'll probably want to create a new table style and apply it to whichever will require less manual work.

Tip: You can use Ctrl > Enter to quick apply styles to tables/cells too!

Comment: Didnt knew there were such things as table styles. Thanks, ill keep this in mind for my next project

Comment: Thanks! For the help! I Will be using styles in correct way for now on. =)

Comment: If this answer worked for you, please marked it as accepted so that the question is marked as answered.